# How to handle nested HTTP requests in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, httprequest, angular7, fork-join

I have a generic service for get data from server. When response received, I'm using a mapper function to map pure JSON data to required model. For some class type in mapper function, I need to get some additional data from server. How can I forcing mapper function wait for second request?

This is my get function:

```
 getChildren(params: ITreeQueryParams): Observable<Optional<T[]>> {
    params.id = isPresent(params.id) ? params.id : 0;
    params.parentId = isPresent(params.parentId) ? params.parentId : 0;
    params.isRoot = isPresent(params.isRoot) ? params.isRoot : false;
    params.additionalId = isPresent(params.additionalId) ? 
    params.additionalId : 0;
    return this.http.get<IListResponse<T>>
(`${this.resourceUrl}/getChildren/${params.id}/${params.parentId}/${params.isRoot}/${params.additionalId}`,
      {
        observe: 'response'
      }).pipe(map((resp) => this.mapResponse(resp,this.model)));
  }
```

This is my mapper function:

```
 protected mapResponse(resp: any, model: IAsset): void {
    if (resp) {
      this.anotherTreeService.getNodeDetail(resp.id, resp.isRoot).subscribe(res => {
        model.additionalData = {canEdit: res.length > 0 ? true : false};
      });
      if (resp.name) {
        model.title = resp.name;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)

Comment: Observable.combineLatest or Observable.forkJoin in RXJS is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's plenty of operators in RxJS that achieve what you want. What you see used quite often, when a data model in itself does not contain all the data and you need a separate call to retrieve additional data based on the first result is an example like this:

```
this.myFirstService.getById(id).pipe(
   map(data => jsonToMyModel(data)),
   tap(model => this.data = model),
   switchMap(model => {
      return this.mySecondService.getListById(model.id)
   }),
   tap(secondData => this.data.list = secondData)
).subscribe()
```

This changes on what you're exactly trying to achieve, as it is possible to have all the data end up in one model returned by the Observable, by using `forkJoin()` or `mergeMap()`. Any of these operators have their usage in these type of situations.

Hope this helps. A more clear and direct example of what you want would require a more complete question with some examples of what you want and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you simply want to make one request and make for it sub requests.

For that purpose you can use `switchMap` and `forkJoin` if you need to take many sub requests.

Here is how you can rewrite your code (I'll write a simplified version)

```
getChildren() {
  this.http.someRequest.pipe(
    tap(response => {
        if (resp.name) {
          model.title = resp.name;
        }
    }),
    switchMap(response =>
        forkJoin(
            response.map(r => this.http.someRequest(r))
        )
    )
  )
}
```

What `switchMap` does is after each source emission (your first observable) it subscribes to the returning observable in a callback (if it was subscribed already it unsubscribes first from callback observable).

`forkJoin` works like `Promise.all`. You can pass there an Array, Object or Multiple observables (now deprecated) and in subscribe you get either an Array or an Object.

Please note that `forkJoin` will emit last value emmitted by each observable **only when all observables complete**. Also, if any observable completes without emitting value `forkJoin` completes without emitting value either. Since all `http.whatever` are observables with one `next` and immediate `complete` after that you don't have to be worried about that.

Also if any observable errors `forkJoin` errors.