# How best to handle nested requests in an angular model without waiting for nested requests to complete

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, service, model

The API for our Angular application has a lot of nested objects referred to by hrefs. I'm trying to map all of these responses to models to get some decoupling between backend and frontend. However, I've come across a problem with these nested hrefs.

Here is an example response from the server:

```
First response:
{
    "firstName": "Steve",
    "lastName": "Mcqueen",
    "account": "api/path/account/some-id-key"
}
```

My issue is: how do I handle the request to fetch the account. There can be 3-4 of these in some cases (or worse, nestled 2-3 levels deep) and I don't always need that data right away. Preferable the request would be handled by a service (AccountService in this example).

I've considered a few approaches. The first and laziest is to in the model simply store the href as a string and fetch it where it is needed.

```
class Client {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    account: string;
}

// in a component
this.clientService.getClient(id).subscribe(client => {
    this.accountService.getAccount(client.account).subscribe(...)
})
```

However, I fear this will get quite messy. Four different components might now be doing the same request at the same time every single time client is updated. It is also not very nice looking having these subscribe-masses everywhere.

Secondly, I thought about letting the service do all the fetching using tap, switchmap like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283581/how-to-handle-nested-http-requests-in-angular-7).

The problem here is that I have to wait for every single request in the model to be resolved before I can start showing any data. If it is like the example above that is fine, but that is not always the case.

Best case would be if I could somehow let the model have Observables instead of the hrefs. So the client model would look something like

```
class Client {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    account: Observable<Account>;
}

// in a component
this.clientService.getClient(id).subscribe(client => {
    client.account.subscribe(...) // no more duplicated requests
})

// In the model adapter
adapt(data) {
    return new Client(
        data.firstName,
        data.lastName,
        this.accountService.getAccount(data.account)
    )
}
```

I am struggling with how I would best map this, however. Since each request creates a new Model, it would end up with a leak since the "old" models wouldn't be unsubscribed. Unless somehow the service would reuse the same observable for the same model href maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

Your Client Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, first } from 'rxjs/operators';

class Client {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  account: Observable<any>;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ClientService {
  // Keep your client list in memory. only hit api one time per client.
  private clientList = {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getClient(id: string): Observable<Client> {
    // if have client in memory return a observable of that client.
    if (this.clientList[id]) {
      return of(this.clientList[id]);
    }

    const url = `http://my_api/clients/${id}`;

    // hit the api to ge the client data.
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map((resp: any) =>
        // builder Method only return the client Instance.
        this.createClient(id, resp.firstName, resp.lastName, resp.accountUrl),
      ),
    );
  }

  private createClient(id, firstName, lastName, accountUrl): Client {
    // BehaviorSubject its a Obvservable that keep the last value emitted in memory
    // when someone subscribe to him, he emit the last value.
    const subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    // subject.asObservable() this method make a Subject as Observable. To block emit method outside this clase.
    const client = { firstName, lastName, account: subject.asObservable() };

    // call to api to get the account data.
    this.http
      .get(accountUrl)
      .pipe(first()) // first operator get the first value emited and unsubscribe.
      .subscribe(accountData => subject.next(accountData)); // emiit the accountn data.

    this.clientList[id] = client;
    return client;
  }
}
```

in your component declare a client attr.

```
client: Client;
```

Call the service

```
this.clientService
  .getClient('21')
  .subscribe(client => (this.client = client));
```

in your html to see the data :

```
{{client.firstName }}
{{client.lastName }}
{{client.account | async | json }}
```

In this way. you can show the data of the client without wait for the data of the account. and hit api one time for the client data and one time for client account. and if u share the services between many componenets you will return the client of the clientList Attr instead of call api again.

Comment: We are heading the right direction, though it does mean we can't update the client. Say we PATCH it or whatever. I'm trying to see if there is a clever way to "force unsubscribe" an observable. So we in some way can declare a model "dead", unsubscribe everything from it, provide a new and resub everything. I'm going to do some tests at work tomorrow.

Comment: maybe u need a BehaviorSubject for each client. when u update a client call the next method for the BehaviorSubject and any subscription will recive the new client data... do you need destroy the subscription? or need keep actualized the client data in each subscription? .

Comment: Yeah I think something like that would work. I will have to think this through more but: as long as the services pass the Subject observables as a reference it should still work just fine, no? It'll still be the same observable and thus it won't leak. Spin up a BehaviourSubject per new request, reuse when a client is updated. I'll get back to you in 12h on that!

Answer (score 0):

In general I like only one subscribe. Imagine we have a function like

```
getObservable(observable) {
    return observable.pipe(
      switchMap((res: any) => {
        const obs=Object.keys(res).find(x=>x.substr(0,4)=="data")
        if (obs) {
          return this.getObservable(res[obs]).pipe(
            map((innerRes) => {
              delete res[obs]
              return { ...res, [obs.substring(4).toLowerCase()]: innerRes }
            })
          )
        }
        else
          return of(res)
      })
    )
  }
```

We can do

```
this.getObservable(myObservable).subscribe(res=>this.data=res)
```

See [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Well, I supouse that all observables begins with data, so I has "dataPersonal","dataAdress"... In the stackblitz I put the observable directly. You can store,e.g. a string with the url and call to the recursive function like

```
getObservable(this.http.get(res[obs]))
```

Or can be an object with url and params